# ssh into remote host after multi-hop ssh tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I used the instructions here to generate a multi-hop ssh-tunnel:

> http://blog.naenius.com/2011/06/ssh-tunneling-across-multiple-hosts-in-linux/

which builds a tunnel like

> 'localhost' -> 'host1' -> 'host2'

In particular, I used:

```
ssh -t -t -L[LOCAL_PORT]:localhost:[PORT_ON_A] [USER]@[SERVER_A] 'ssh -L[PORT_ON_A]:localhost:[PORT_ON_B] [USER]@[SERVER_B]'
```

which, after executing, opens up a terminal on host2.

Now that I have done that, I would like to connect via ssh directly to host2 from localhost, which I would have naively expected that is achieved by:

```
ssh localhost:[LOCAL_PORT]
```

However, I only get:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost:2345: Name or service not
>   known

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Tried machine IP:

```
ssh [MACHINE_IP]:[LOCAL_PORT]
```

but it also does not work.

However, here's something that does work

If I do:

```
ssh -L 1234:[SERVER_B]:22 [USER]@[SERVER_A]
```

I can then copy directly from my machine to SERVER_B via:

scp -P 1234 local_path_to_file [USER]@127.0.0.01:

but this:

```
ssh 127.0.0.01:1234
```

returns

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname 127.0.0.01:1234: Name or service not
>   known

Not sure if that's revealing

EDIT2: This is /etc/hosts

```
cat /etc/hosts                                                                                                                                                    
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Comment: Try without the "01". Like this: 127.0.0.1. Also, can you post the contents of your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 also results in the same issue. I pasted the contents of hosts, hope that helps.

Comment: Ports to SSH over for the main connection are specified with `-p`, not a `:suffix`.

`ssh -p [LOCAL_PORT] localhost`

Comment: aha! that worked, thanks a lot. Want to make that an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ssh 127.0.0.01:1234
```

The [OpenSSH `ssh` utility](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh.1), which is probably what you're using here, doesn't permit you to specify a port this way. It's taking the entire string "127.0.0.01:1234" and trying to resolve it as a hostname.

The correct way to run this is:

```
ssh -p 1234 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Yeah, somebody else commented with that solution, I offered to make it an answer to that I could accept but he didn't reply. Accepting this since it's the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are firewall restrictions denying you access to `[PORT_ON_B]` directly from `SERVER_A`, you can do just this:

```
ssh -L[LOCAL_PORT]:[SERVER_B]:[PORT_ON_B] [USER]@[SERVER_A]
```

After that:

```
ssh localhost:[LOCAL_PORT]
```

Provided there is a SSH SERVER listening on `[SERVER_B][PORT_ON_B]`.

Your approach should also work. You should check that both SSH SERVERs support tunnelling (although it's enabled by default, it could be disabled on server configuration).

Comment: just to be clear, "localhost" is not a variable or a placeholder, it's literally the word "localhost", right?

Comment: Correct @elelias. It's literally the word "localhost". If that doesn't work, maybe your `/etc/hosts` is not properly established. Try using your machine's IP address instead.